# Why is my row not getting deleted? (R studio)

Tags: r

I have a dataset, in which a particular row wants to be deleted, say 5398th row with color = blue

I have tried both the below code, but it doesn't work and no error as well, R behaves as if the code has executed but with no changes in the data.

```
    df <- df[ df$color != "Blue", , drop=FALSE]; 
    df <- df[-c(5398),]
```

Why is this happening and what has to be done in order to delete the row that doesn't get deleted?

Comment: 1250217 no.of rows are present.... even after running the code above, same rows are present.

Comment: Can you post as well the code that creates the data set and any significant lines between that and your current snippet? You're current code should work so it's probably something else or how you are checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes a while for the environment window to display the changes. Have you pressed the refresh button in the environment variable list? Your operations should work. Sample below.

```
df = data.table(
  x = c('Blue', 'Green')
)

> df1 = df[-1]; nrow(df1)
[1] 1

> df2 = df[x != 'Blue']; nrow(df2)
[1] 1

> all.equal(df1, df2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nothing works actually, I have also restarted R and also my PC and tried it for some reason.

Comment: Can you run typeof(df$color)?